# Badge that is achieved by most number of people

Tags: discussion, badges

Which is the gold badge that is achieved by most number of people? Which is the second one?

Where can I see such a statistics in SO?

Comment: Please see a complaint and an answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148147/why-isnt-class-exposed-for-badges-in-data-explorer

Comment: @AaronBertrand Any idea why this much down vote on this question?

Comment: Possibly lack of research (since most of the info you're after is readily available in obvious places), or possibly because people don't agree this information is useful. Remember, [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) and rep here is pretty meaningless. I didn't down-vote, for what it's worth.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Due to this down voting I am prevented from asking questions in meta. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: I looked over your questions, and I think you are demonstrating part of the problem right here: asking questions that could most certainly be answered by a search. [I suggest you read this very thoroughly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers). However I suspect that a question ban on meta is harder to overcome than on the main site. Hopefully I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go at the [badges page and order by class](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold), you'll notice that [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question) is currently the gold badge that has been awarded the most times (31997).

However several of the badges can be awarded to the same user multiple times, so those numbers only tell you how many times the badge has been awarded, but not to how many people, unless of course the badge is one of those that can only be awarded once.

If you really want to know the counts per user, a [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/) would be your only way (and yes, you'd probably have to write it yourself).

Comment: Thanks. I used following query SELECT * FROM Badges ORDER BY Name. How do I filter query to know whether the badge is Gold?

Comment: @Lijo I have absolutely no idea ;)

Comment: OP asked a follow up [question on Meta ProgSE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/querying-badges-table-in-data-stackexchange), and it seems that the simple solution would be to hardcode the gold badges' IDs in the query...

Comment: @Yannis there must be a way to discover class, unless it is just not exposed in Data Explorer for some reason (and perhaps that is a bug). After all, your profile and other badges pages allow you to sort/filter by class. So that metadata must be available somewhere.

Comment: @Yannis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148147/why-isnt-class-exposed-for-badges-in-data-explorer

Comment: @AaronBertrand Don't know why the badge class is not searchable, but just checked the API and [it's the same there too](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#order=desc&sort=rank&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Answer (score 3):

If you visit the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) and sort the [badges by class](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold), the numbers next to the badge listing show how many times this badge has been awarded.

[image]

Keep in mind that there are some gold badges that can be awarded multiple times to the same user. So this number is not how many users have been awarded the badge, rather how many **times** the badge has been awarded.

Comment: ohh.. so big different between fantic & famous... It seems, famous is really very **famous**

Comment: Not how many people; it shows how many *times* it has been awarded. Jon Skeet received the `Famous Question` badge 5 times so far, for example. You do state it correctly below the screenshot but your sentence above it is inconsistent. :-)

Comment: @mar - thanks for that :) Fixed.