# Constructive Question Closed as Non Constructive

Tags: discussion

This is not a question, it is a comment.

This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148117/badge-that-is-achieved-by-most-number-of-people) was closed as non-constructive.  But the three questions within it all have exact, non-debatable, non-subjective answers.  They were:

- what is the most awarded badge?  There can be only one answer here, no debate.
- what is the second most awarded badge?  Again, only one answer.
- where can I see the statistics?  Ok, maybe there is more than one place to view them, but certainly the options won't elicit debate or chatty long winded discussion.

I just felt I had to share this.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites, not C&A or C&C sites.

Comment: @Jack Maney:  The user asked valid questions, with non-subjective answers.  I really don't understand how anyone considers it non-constructive.

Comment: I felt question was **Too localized**, but question was closed as **not constructive** by the other users.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick - Irrelevant. Questions are for **asking questions**. Comments are for comments. There is a difference.

Comment: @Jack Maney:  Oh, your referring to my post.  Yes, I purposely broke the rules and expect to pay the downvote price, and an eventual closing.  But I felt I had to say something.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick - Moderator flags exist for a reason. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @Jack Maney:  Agreed.  Was not aware of the option.  Won't happen again.

Comment: btw the question in question was re-opened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is not a question, it is a comment.
>
> ...
>
> I just felt I had to share this.

Please don't do that, by posting a question you are pushing other, perhaps more useful questions out of the way.

If you feel the question was closed incorrectly, vote to re-open. If you don't yet have the privilege to vote to re-open, flag it for moderation attention and ask for it to be re-opened. Lastly, if you just want to comment, then comment.

Simple as that.

Comment: Agreed.  I was not aware of the other options, and I really felt compelled to say something.  Sorry.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick No worries, for the record I agree that the question shouldn't have been closed and have already voted to re-open it.