# How to get type of the badge (Bronze, Silver, Gold) from Data Explorer?

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer

I was just curious who have the most Gold, Silver or Bronze badges but I can't find the field in Data Explorer that represents the type of the badge. Either it's missing or I can't find it.

So, how to get the type of the badge in DE?

Comment: there is none http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148147/can-we-expose-class-for-badges-in-data-explorer